# vim tex_conceal not working inside a function

Tags: vim, latex, tex, neovim

I want to set `let g:tex_conceal=""` to disable mathematical symbols appearing instead of original text in a `.tex` file (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18161073/11542729)) in my `.vimrc`.

This setting is not working if I do it inside a function like

```
function! New_function()
    let g:tex_conceal=""
endfunction
autocmd BufReadPost,BufNewFile *.tex, call New_function()
```

Why is it not working? Other things I do inside a function are working correctly except this.

Also, these math symbols do not expand even if the cursor is over them in both normal and insert mode.

I am not using any latex related plugins.

Comment: You need to just set the variable globally. Trying to do it in a function doesnt make sense

Comment: Yes globally setting it works. But I want to know why does it not work here. Other variables work just fine. Is there any reason that I am not aware of?

Comment: My guess is it’s too late: the syntax with conceal has probably been setup before you changed the variable. You could try bufreadpre, but the function changes the same variable every time, so just got with a single let in your vimrc and be done with it